# RewriteRule for a really transparent rewriting?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I go with my browser to the URL :

http://home.fr/kcozs4ip/mypicture.jpg

with this `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /                
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                       
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://home.fr/$1_$2 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Then the server will reach the file http://home.fr/kcozs4ip_mypicture.jpg

That's good : it works, because my file is actually saved on the server at this place.

But then, in the browser, the file is downloaded with filename = `kcozs4ip_mypicture.jpg` instead of the name `mypicture.jpg`.

**How to make that the browser sees http://home.fr/kcozs4ip/mypicture.jpg as a file whose filename is `mypicture.jpg`?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `http://` from target URL to avoid redirecting the URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /                

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                       
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1_$2 [L] 
</IfModule
```

Comment: Is browser url still changing to `http://example.com/files/9e0y1cqt`? If yes then try testing in a different browser?

Comment: I removed the question about MIME-TYPE, which in fact was irrevelant and not important in my question @anubhava. Sorry for having been unclear at first. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Hmm alright. Will you be fine if browser URL changes to `http://home.fr/mypicture.jpg` as well?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, it works now!  Why removing `http://` in the target URL avoid redirecting the URL ? It's a mystery for me :)

Comment: It is documented in apache manuals also, if you specify http:// in the target URL then apache will send R=302 to browser/current.